# What is special about the na1 instance that it gets releases two weeks early?

Tags: release, developer-edition, pre-release, summer-15

From [8 Key Dates for the Summer '15 Release](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2015/04/8-key-dates-summer-15-release.html)

> ## May 22nd — NA1 upgraded
>
> The first release weekend is when we at salesforce.com and any customers on NA1 get upgraded.
>
> ## June 5th — The second release weekend
>
> This is when another set of instances — NA6, NA7, NA8, NA9, NA17, NA18, NA22 and EU5 — gets upgraded. Check out our Trust page to see when you’ll be upgraded.
>
> ## June 12th and 13th — The final release weekend
>
> All remaining Salesforce systems will be upgraded over this weekend. This is also the upgrade weekend for any Sandboxes you’ve opted not to include in the Sandbox preview.

Is NA1 specifically reserved for Salesforce's internal use and for select customers or can anyone get an instance on NA1?

My assumption is that Salesforce are [dogfooding](https://youtu.be/eiYoBbEZwlk?t=4m20s) it against their own orgs before releasing it to the other pods.

I'd really like to get a developer edition instance on there to test out Summer `15 release features before they reach my packaging orgs.

I guess I could keep creating new developer edition orgs in the hope of getting one on NA1, but I'm not sure if accounts are randomly allocated to the available pods.

Comment: I'm at least 90% certain I've worked on a NA1 instance before, and it was a full production environment for a customer. This was ~2 years ago though, so it might have changed?

Comment: My first instance was on NA1. There are definitely still customers on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although NA1 is not used *exclusively* by Salesforce, the biggest organization there is definitely the one Salesforce uses to run most of its internal business. So yes, the basic idea is an extra chance to dogfood before we roll out to the majority of customers' production environments.